# Is there a good process monitoring and control framework in either Ruby or Perl?

Tags: ruby, perl

I came across [God](http://god.rubyforge.org/) which seems good but I am wondering if anyone knows of other process monitoring and control frameworks that I can compare god with.
God has the following features:

1. Config file is written in Ruby
2. Easily write your own custom conditions in Ruby
3. Supports both poll and event based conditions
4. Different poll conditions can have different intervals
5. Integrated notification system (write your own too!)
6. Easily control non-daemonizing scripts

The last one is what i am having difficulty with.

Comment: Are you having difficulties using it, understanding it, finding it elsewhere or what?

Comment: adamse,
How do i use god to monitor a background process, started as nohup <something.pl> &

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`Ubic`](http://github.com/berekuk/Ubic) ([CPAN page here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Ubic/) but do read installation details on the github project page).

[`Ubic`](http://github.com/berekuk/Ubic) isn't a monitoring framework par se but a [LSB compliant](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html) extensible Service Manager.

Its written and configurable all in Perl.  A simple example would be:

```
# /etc/ubic/services/test

use Ubic::Service::SimpleDaemon;
return Ubic::Service::SimpleDaemon->new({ bin => "sleep 1000" });
```

To start above is:  `ubic start test`.  To check its running or not: `ubic status test`.  To stop service (suprisingly!) is: `ubic stop test`.

[`Ubic`](http://github.com/berekuk/Ubic) keeps an eye on all its services so when `test` service stops after 1000 seconds then [`Ubic`](http://github.com/berekuk/Ubic) will automatically restart it again.

Some more links:

- [Mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/ubic-perl)
- [Ubic - how to implement your first service (blog post)](http://blogs.perl.org/users/vyacheslav_matjukhin/2010/08/ubic---how-to-implement-your-first-service.html)
- [Ubic - code reuse and customizations (blog post)](http://blogs.perl.org/users/vyacheslav_matjukhin/2010/08/ubic---code-reuse-and-customizations.html)

/I3az/

Answer (score 2):

I am a big fan of [Monit](http://mmonit.com/).  It's [written in C](http://www.ohloh.net/p/monit), but does everything you want.

I particularly liked that I was able to compile a thin version that worked beautifully on an ARM based system with only 64 MB of RAM.

You might want to read [God vs Monit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768184/god-vs-monit) on SO to get a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

**[Bluepill](http://github.com/arya/bluepill) is a great process monitoring/administration framework.**

- It's **written in Ruby** but it can **monitor anything**, I use it to monitor Unicorn processes.
- It even runs on 1.9.2.
- **Doesn't leak memory.**
- Has support for **demonizing processes** that don't demonize themselves.
- All around **easy**, even with RVM!

Comment: How do you get bluepill to start one process after another? - for example start the web application only if the database is started?