# Can I automatically start a daemon in a Rails 2.3.11 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon

In the development environment i use the following command to start a daemon after starting the server:

```
RAILS_ENV=development lib/daemons/mailer_ctl start
```

In the production environment, from the application directory, i would use:

```
lib/daemons/mailer_ctl start
```

Can i change the development.rb and production.rb files so the daemon would automatically be started? If not, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend on your production server you use god (or something similar) to watch for the existing of a process, and start it if it does not exist

http://god.rubyforge.org/

Monit is an alternative -- here's a good SO question on [monit vs god](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768184/god-vs-monit)

Comment: Jesse, i used the Railscasts configuration with the mailer.god file in the config directory. When i execute script/server god is not starting automatically. After i start god manually everything works fine. Am i missing something?

Comment: "script/server god" is not the way to start god. With that command, you're staring the rails server in the "god" environment. You should start god manually once.

Comment: i didn't use "script/server god". i know script/server starts the rails server but was expecting god to start when the server started. If i have to restart apache, will i need to start god again?

Comment: No, god will survive an apache restart. It will not, by default, survive a server reboot though. I'd have capistrano start/stop god whenever you deploy, and look into an init.d script to start god on reboots.